# How to make circles of growing in sizes from small to big in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am a newbie in Photoshop.. i want to make circles in Photoshop which look like growing in sizes from small to big vertically... I have attached a picture along so you guys might get an idea... or please let me know if i can do it by using illustrator more easily... fast reply appreciated... !

[image]

Comment: This does not warrant a question, a simple google would have solved this.

Answer (score 5):

As you've tagged Illustrator I'll give you that option.

- Create your biggest circle and your smallest circle and place x distance apart.

[image]

- Select both circles and go `Object > Blend > Make`.

[image]

- Then go `Object > Blend > Blend Options` and set your amount of circles in between the first and last.

[image]

- If you want you can then go `Object > Expand` to "release" the circles.

[image]

Done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much... appreciated a lot... can you help me out to one more time? please...

Comment: Hey, you stole my circle question!

Comment: You can't win them all! @CircleB

Answer (score 3):

Copy. Paste in Place. Cmd+T. Shrink the percentage. Repeat.